# Keep all parameters updated from Flask to HTML by changing

Tags: html, flask, render

I built a simple webapp with Flask. There are three forms in HTML with inputs. When I change the input, send it and if I want to keep all the value displayed, I have to render_template and send the value from backend to the frontend. This means, whenever I change one parameter, I have to render_template and send all the parameters in it. Is it the only solution or is there any smarter way to display parameters?

Comment: Standard HTML behavior is that if you submit a form (click on submit button), it will reload the page. If you don't want that, you have to programmatically submit the form i.e using Javascript, intercept the form when user clicks on 'submit', then submit the form yourself using Javascript. See example code [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-stop-refreshing-the-page-on-submit-in-javascript)